# InfoPath 2010: Query data from SQL Server but limit update to two columns

Tags: sql-server, infopath

Found out I have this wonderful software on my PC after working here for almost 3 years :)

So, with that said, I am a complete newbie at this. I can do the basics, which is mostly all I'll need to do with what I'm looking for, except I haven't seen how to do what I want.

What I want to do is query a SQL Server 2008 database table, gather specific data, but have end users only be able to update 2 columns of the data.

Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTzFM.png

In the above image, I want the highlighted columns to be editable to the database and the others set as read-only.

If I right click on the columns and edit the Text Box properties, there's an option in the Display tab called 'Read-only', which is probably what I'm looking for...right?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEkC4.png

I guess my question is, am I on the right track here? Do I create a general user in SQL Server that can read and write to the table and it will work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are on the right track.  All those fields that you don't want changed need to be marked as read only.
As for SQL Server users, you may be better off creating a Role and setting the permissions on that role.  Then add your users to that role.